# MVC web Api HttpContext.user

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am a little bit confused for HttpContext.User object on WebApi/mvc controllers, As we know httpcontext is whole info for specific request 
but i don't know what is the "user" at the httpContetx.user is it represent a header, cookies for specific request?
what is behind this syntactic sugar, I understand that i should set it  to Principal. But for what HttpContext.User is translate when request/response accrued

Comment: its used to support the authentication model in asp.net and you can extend it if needed.

Answer (score 1):

It is used for authentication and authorization. You use it to get the users context. Such as this simple one `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` but you have to assign these programmatically in order for it to hold any context, hence, cookies.

It can also grab your `HttpContext.User.Name` if you have a login setup using Identity.

Does this answer you questions?

Comment: hi, not really. i still do not understand from where httpcontext  take the user identity information and what is authenticated user